# Golang - how to run a command referring to a package

Tags: go

I am new to Golang, and trying to run a command from the following package:

https://github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest

The command proposed in the Quick Start section of the package is:

```
growforest -train train.fm -rfpred forest.sf -target B:FeatureName
```

but I am not sure how to use the command.

I have cloned the package on my D drive, and tried running it in Ms-dos window and get an error:

```
d:\DATA-SCIENCE\Go>go run growforest -train train.fm -rfpred forest.sf -target B:FeatureName
go run: no go files listed
```

I also tried running the command inside a go file, but that doesn't work either:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest"
)

func main() {
    growforest -train train.fm -rfpred forest.sf -target B:FeatureName
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how this is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the package first

```
go install
```

Then the `growforest`  command will be available in your `GOPATH\bin` (which should be part of your PATH environment variable)

Ideally, you should do a `go get github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest`, which will clone and build and install the repo in `GOPATH/src/github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest`.
See "[Download and install packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)".

From the README, you need to install specific parts of the project:

```
go get github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest
go install github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest/growforest
go install github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest/applyforest

#optional utilities
go install github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest/leafcount
go install github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest/utils/nfold
go install github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest/utils/toafm
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the GOPATH\bin part.